# Is this question really a SWR?

Tags: discussion, tags

This one: [1920's terms for parents/children](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202642/1920s-terms-for-parents-children)

It doesnt strike me as a single word request, and since it's a new user, they probably haven't figured it out yet. To me, SWR means questions like 'What is the word for ...', [for example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6170/is-there-a-word-or-phrase-for-the-feeling-you-get-after-looking-at-a-word-for-to).

*However*, a mod has edited this post and left it in, so I'm not sure whether I am justified.

Comment: There are other problems with the content of the post, like no signs of research, but I don't see anything that leads me to believe it's not a request for a single word (or two single words).

Comment: Thanks, @Hank. I'm probably blinded by the constant 'what's a word for someone who likes cheese' and the like...

Comment: Those are definitely the bulk of them but they are not the best ones. Those are the shortest and most likely to be tediously easy or impossible.

Comment: The question in question could easily be reworded to "What is the word kids would use for their parents ...?".

Comment: I think it's not the usual SWR we see. It's asking for historical terms. It could be reworded to "what were the words kids used in the 19xxs to call their father and mother?" or something.

Comment: One of the odder distinctions that we make at EL&U is between requests for a particular word (as in "what term would children in England in the 1920s have used for a parent?"), which we accept as SWRs, and  requests for all words that fit a defined category (as in "what terms might children in England in the 1920s have used for a parent?"), which we (at least in some instances) treat as open-ended list requests and therefore reject as off-topic. To my mind, almost every SWR is, at bottom, a request for an open-ended list of relevant suggestions, from which the OP can then choose a favorite.

Comment: @SvenYargs, yeah, I suppose the open ended type is is what I thought a SWR *should* be...